# AdMob/iAd mediation, iAd doesn't load

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, admob

I added the following code for iAd banner in my `viewDidLoad` and `GameOver` methods.

```
self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 50)];
[self.bannerView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
```

In `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` method, I made sure that the AdMob banner loads when iAd doesn't have Ad to show.

So, in the `viewDidLoad` method, iAd and AdMob mediate okay, but in the `GameOver` method, only AdMob always shows up. How come iAd never shows up in `GameOver` method when I put the same code in both methods?